# io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing, illegal-input

I am trying to parse JSON in kotlin where I have a suspend function returning a list but it is giving an error `io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input`. The function is as follows

```
 private suspend fun fetchMenu(): List<MenuItems> {
    return httpClient.
        get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/main/littleLemonSimpleMenu.json")
        .body()

}
```

It shows the error is in `body` line.

The `MenuItems` class is

```
@Serializable
data class MenuItems(
 
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val price: Int

  ) {

fun toMenuItemRoom() = MenuItemRoom(
    
    id,title,price.toDouble()
 )
}
```

How can I parse it to avoid the error?

Comment: Price is a String.

Comment: I changed it but result is same.